# Change background color of div based on a value

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax

I am trying to make my basket button have a circular div background turn blue after an item is added to the basket, so far the add to basket function is working perfectly with ajax I just can't somehow toggle background from none to display based on for example if the basket has 1 or more items the background needs to be blue and if the basket has 0 items then background set to none, here is what I have tried so far:

```
if($objBasket->number_of_items > 0) {
    $background = "block";
} else {
    $background = "none";
}

?>
<p class="in-cart" style="background:<?php echo $background; ?>"><?php echo $objBasket->number_of_items; ?></p>
```

And the js:

```
function refreshMiniBasket() {

        $.ajax({

            url: '../modules/basket_mini_nav_refresh.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(k, v) {
                    $(".in-cart").text(v);
                });
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert('Error occurred');
            }

        });

    }
```

But this only changes the background state when I manually reload the page

Comment: 1. What does `data` return?
2. Do your php like this for further updates and flexibility:  <?php
    $extra_basket_items = $objBasket->number_of_items > 0 ? 'has-basket-items' : 'no-basket-items';
?>
<p class="in-cart <?php echo $extra_basket_items; ?>"><?php echo $objBasket->number_of_items; ?></p>

Answer (score 0):

Put the code for changing the background inside the `success:` of the Ajax call.

```
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(k, v) {
                $(".in-cart").text(v);
            });

            // Update the JS variable that keeps track
            // of the number of items in the cart.

            // if that variable is > 0, set the background to blue.
            // else, set the background to transparent.
        },
```

Comment: No now the ajax freezes and the add to basket function doesnt work anymore

Comment: I do not seem to understand you as to what I have to actually write down for this to work the number_of_items is loaded from a class called Basket that I have as soon as I instantiate the class or whatever php code I put in the success callback the code freezes

Comment: So the only variable that you have for knowing how many items are in the cart is in the server side (php), not in the client side (js)?

Comment: You should keep another variable in the client side (JavaScript) to know how many items are in the cart. It will make your life easier.

Comment: you mean like an ajax get method to always keep tracking the cart items?

Comment: I mean that every time the user adds something in the cart, you change both things. The variable in the server side (I guess you keep it in the user session) and the variable in the client side. And, just in case the user refreshes the page, I would add a function to query the server side, retrieve the quantity of items in the cart, and update the client side variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a job for `javascript / jquery` than `php`. You can set the initial state of the basket in php, but should make live changes of the basket's state from javascript.

Change your basket's look inside the `successCallback` of your ajax.

```
function refreshMiniBasket() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '../modules/basket_mini_nav_refresh.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            //...

            if (parseInt($(".in-cart").text()) > 0)
                $(".in-cart").show();
            else
                $(".in-cart").hide();
        },
        error: function (data) {
            //...
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: this freezed my code unfortunately because I have to instantiate the basket class to get the value and use the if statement here and that does not work.

Comment: with this code the number of items cant be seen because it is not being called I guess?

Comment: Are you trying to use the `numberOfItems` variable I have in my code? You wouldn't have that variable in your code. Since I don't have the full code I don't know where you keep that data, it was just put in there as a logical placeholder. From what I know, you seem to be writing it into the `.in-cart`'s text so try `if(parseInt($(".in-cart").text()) > 0)` instead.

Comment: unfortunately this does not work, when the page loads the in cart is still visibile in the beginning and when I add an item to the basket then the in-cart dissapears but does not come back even if I remove the item again